# cognito aws user info IDP link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In the AWS cognito - In sinup and sigin actions we are doing using **`amazon-cognito-identity-js`**

I've done all the sign up and sin in steps as per npm docs.

I configure open ID `OIDC` link and I'm trying to get the user info by passing access token through end point

```
https://<your-user-pool-domain>/oauth2/userInfo
                Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

But it throwing an error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Access token does not contain openid scope"
}
```

I'm not able to figure what is the issue exactly behind this error

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your user pool client? Which scopes does it include in the requested tokens?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Go into Federation -> Identity Providers. In the "Authorize scope" field, add "openid". Note that scopes are separated by spaces, for example "openid email".

2. Go into App Integration -> App Client settings. Find the App Client you are connecting to, in "Allowed OAuth Scopes" tick "openid".

Comment: I've done this step too but still the same error.

Comment: I'd recommend running the flow manually using https://openidconnect.net/. Does the token returned from your openid endpoint include the openid scope?